# SQL update rows with counter

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I would like to know how to loop through each record in a database, and update them using a counter.

For instance, I have a large number of email fields. I would like to update them all using the pattern: 'hello+1@gmail.com', 'hello+2@gmail.com', 'hello+3@gmail.com', 'hello+4@gmail.com' ...

I tried to do this without SQL in my Rails console, but it would take too much time. Any suggestions on how to do this using SQL?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL server:

```
select <stuff>
       ,row_number() over (order by <something>) as row_number
from <things>
where <something>
```

Will do the trick. If not, let us know what you are using and we can go from there! Are you looking to put the '+Row_number' before the @? If so it should be a fairly simple matter of replacing the the '@' with  '+4@' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would use variables:

```
update table t
    set email = concat('hello+', @rn := coalesce(@rn, 0) + 1, '@gmail.com');
```

If you have a particular ordering in mind, you can add an `order by` clause.